# Bad news email, what does it mean?

Tags: jagged-alliance-2

I'm playing on the jagged alliance 2 [1.13 fanpatch/mod](http://ja2v113.pbworks.com/w/page/4218339/FrontPage).

While playing the game, and just killing an army patrol, I suddenly got the following message. I didn't lose any of my mercs, or any sectors.

> Bad News Do not allow your confidence to waiver. The situation is
>   temporary. It was only a matter of time before Deidranna's forces made
>   the necessary adjustments.
>
> I have faith in you and your team. Enrico Chivaldori

Apparantly something bad happend. But I have no idea what. Does somebody know what this triggers? What has just been triggered? Why I'm getting this message now. (in other games, I also got this email, but at different times while playing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message means that you were a sitting duck without major battles for a too long time. As a consequence, locals will be aware that you are not making actual progress, leading to a slight drop of loyalty in all the towns you control.

Depending on your settings, you can either simply waiver this message, or hunt down enemies and/or side quests to compensate for lost loyalty. You can also consider preparing for assault on another city or SAM site, unless your only remaining objective is Meduna.

Comment: Oddly enough. I had this message appear after I lost some drassen provinces. But iirc I didn't have militia in those provinces. Btw by default loyalty loss by sitting around is off in 1.13 (you can turn it on in the xml options).